# is css scroll-snap api supported by React?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, scroll-snap

I tried to implement the css scroll-snap api in a simple create-react-app application. And it seems that it is not working.

So, I'm wondering if it is supported, or if there is a special way to do it with react?

Comment: React does not "support" css features, the browser is responsible for that. https://caniuse.com/#search=snap

Answer (score 2):

The thing that helped me solve the problem is that the scroll-snap-type property has to be attached to the html tag:

```
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```